# Power BI DAX RankX only returns 1

Tags: dax, rank

I am new in Dax and I am studying the Rankx function.
I have a simple table with Id, price, product, category.

When I use the function in the folowing way I only get rank 1 for all products and I am not understood why.

```
RankX = RANKX(
        all(dProduto),
        SUM(dProduto[preco])
)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RANKX`  is used to rank rows based on a specific expression. In your example, you are trying to rank products based on their price.

Since you are using `ALL(dProduto)`, that means you are considering all the rows in the `dProduto` table. (This part seems fine).

But for  **SUM(dProduto[preco])** here lies the problem. You are trying to rank the sum of all the prices from the `dProduto` table. This will always return the same value (the total sum) for each row, thus every row gets the same rank of 1.

I assume that you have a ProductID column in your table, the measure is like below :

```
RankX = RANKX(
    ALL(dProduto[id]), 
    CALCULATE(SUM(dProduto[preco]))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. 
But it does not work, because in your code (in the second parameter) you are using a table instead expression (like a aggregation function as sumx).
However I have tried sumx as well but still did not work.